# How to use Python to import CSV data to Google Sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So, a Python script reads data from a CSV file and appends it to a Google Sheet. However, this script is not optimized and there are several improvements that can be made.

Improvements are needed for the script by implementing the following features(Help me implement them):

==> Parse the CSV file correctly: The script currently copies all values after the colons and pastes them into the Google Sheet, (see the tradedata.csv). However, some values may contain special characters or units that should be removed before appending to the sheet.

==> Match the CSV headers to the Google Sheet columns: The headers in the CSV file do not match the order of the columns in the Google Sheet(link at the bottom), this a feature that is key, because the script is eventually going to be reading data from different types of CSV files, and so the arrangement of the headers in the CSV file versus the names of the google sheet columns should not affect the python code. The script should be updated to locate the correct columns in the sheet and append the values in the appropriate cells.

==> Ignore unnecessary data: Not all values in the CSV file should be appended to the Google Sheet. The script should be updated to only append the necessary values since the CSV file may contain unimportant data.

==> Error handling: The script should be able to handle errors such as incorrect file paths or missing columns in the Google Sheet.

To sum up, here's how the CSV file looks like with the headers each number:

- Market type: v.100.1
- Comment: Stick with winners
- Max Consecutive Losses: 1
- Highest Stake: $2.15
- Trades: 6
- Max Consecutive Wins: 2
- Stake: 0.5
- Max Drawdown: 0.082
- Highest Stake Date: 11:19:10
- Gross Profit: $6.30
- Gross Loss: $2.00
- Avg Profit Per Trade: $0.57
- Avg Win Trade: $1.57
- Avg Loss Trade: $1.00
- Ratio Avg Win/Loss: 1.57
- Time Playing: 00:05:42

And here's how the sheet columns are arranged and and named:

- Market
- Stake
- Trades
- Consec. Loss
- Highest Stake
- Max Drawdown
- Consec. Wins
- Win:Loss Ratio
- Winrate %
- Overall Time
- Profit / Trade
- Comment

I haven't had alot of luck running the code, the code appends alot of unnecessary information on google sheets extracted from the csv file. Without filtering it, despite the code having the Key Mapping function, that should enable it parse the necessary values. I've been stuck on this one problem for weeks, anyone out-there pleease.

The full project is on my repo https://github.com/waraga2/SheetMagic

Below is the Python script with the Key Mapping function to map the csv file headers to those of the corresponding sheet column names:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import csv

# Define the name of the CSV file and Google Sheets file
CSV_FILE = "tradedata.csv"
SHEETS_FILE = "trading sheet"

# Define the mapping of CSV headers to sheets headers
HEADER_MAPPING = {
    "Market type": "Market",
    "Stake": "Stake",
    "Trades": "Trades",
    "Max Consecutive Losses": "Consec. Loss",
    "Highest Stake": "Highest Stake",
    "Max Drawdown": "Max Drawdown",
    "Max Consecutive Wins": "Consec. Wins",
    "Ratio Avg Win/Loss": "Win:Loss Ratio",
    "Wins": "Winrate %",
    "Time Playing": "Overall Time",
    "Avg Profit Per Trade": "Profit / Trade",
    "Comment": "Comment"
}

def extract_data():
    with open(CSV_FILE, 'r') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file)
        extracted_data = {}
        for row in data:
            try:
                key, value = extract_key_value(row[0])
                extracted_data[key] = transform_value(key, value)
            except KeyError:
                pass
    return extracted_data

def extract_key_value(row):
    split_row = row.split(":", 1)
    key = split_row[0].strip()
    value = split_row[1].strip() if len(split_row) > 1 else ""
    return key, value

def transform_value(key, value):
    if key == "Winrate %":
        return value.split("(")[1].replace("%)", "")
    elif key == "Profit / Trade":
        return value.replace("$", "")
    elif key == "Max Drawdown":
        return value.split("(")[0].strip()
    else:
        return value

def append_to_sheets():
    extracted_data = extract_data()
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my-trading-project-384611-98e812573160.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open(SHEETS_FILE).sheet1
    sheet.append_row(list(extracted_data.values()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    append_to_sheets()
```